# Delta function $\delta_{n,m}$ with two variables $n, m$

Tags: kronecker-delta

I am trying to understand the equations below. What seems to be confusing me is the use of two variables $n, m$ in the delta function: $\delta_{n,m}$. I understand that `d_n` would just be the spoke at `x=n`, but I have no idea how to use `m`.

I hope the question makes sense. I'm rather new to this so excuse the potentially basic question.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually the [*Kronecker* delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta), as @ShubhamJohri defined. You can prove these equations by writing each integrand as half a sum or difference. (Note these equations implicitly assume $m,\,n$ are integers.) For example, the second equation admits the proof$$\begin{align}\int_0^T\tfrac12\left[\cos\tfrac{\pi(n-m)t}{T}-\cos\tfrac{\pi(n+m)t}{T}\right]dt&=\tfrac{1}{2\pi}\left[\tfrac{\pi t}{T}\operatorname{sinc}\tfrac{\pi(n-m)t}{T}-\tfrac{T}{n+m}\sin\tfrac{\pi(n+m)t}{T}\right]_0^T\\&=\tfrac12T\delta_{nm}-0,\end{align}$$where $\operatorname{sinc}$ is the [unnormalized sinc function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function). In particular, it helps to evaluate the leftmost contribution separately in the cases $m=n,\,m\ne n$.

Answer (score 1):

$\delta_{n,m}=\begin{cases}1,&n=m\\0,&n\ne m\end{cases}$